# Ext.MessageBox.confirm custom buttons

Tags: javascript, button, extjs

Is it possible to add custom buttons to the Ext.MessageBox.confirm. By custom I mean custom text and custom number of buttons...

```
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Delete', 'Are you sure ?', 

function(btn){
   if(btn === 'yes'){
      return true;
   }
   else{
      return false;
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 14):

Try setting the `buttonText`, like:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Delete',
        message: 'Are you sure ?',
        width: 300,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
        buttonText: {
            yes: 'Yesssss!!!',
            no: 'Nooo!!!'
        }
    });
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12bq

Comment: `buttons: 15` will result with 4 buttons (Yes, No, Ok & Cancel), I think you'll need to override the class if you want additional buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below

```
Ext.Msg.show({ 
  title: 'Enter Message', 
  msg: null, 
  buttons: [{ 
    itemId: 'ok',  
    text: 'Send',   
    ui: 'action' 
  }, {
    itemId: 'cancel',   
    text: 'Cancel'    
  }], 
  prompt: {   
    maxlength: 180,   
    autocapitalize: false
  },   
  fn: function(text,btn) {
    // do some stuff
  }  
});
```

Comment: Though the answer needs some polishing, this should have been the accepted answer